# Not able to access POST data in Spring Security custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on an application where I need access to the POST data `JSON`. My code is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class LoginFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    System.out.println("filtered /login request: " +  servletRequest.getParameter("idToken"));
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }
}
```

when I run the application

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"idToken" : "EWRE@#$RWER@#23434W$"}' http://localhost:8080/login
```

I get `null` on the log

```
2017-05-06 06:23:31.153  INFO 89727 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 2 ms
filtered /login request: null
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `ServletRequest.getParameter(...)` only retrieves request parameters. You  probably have to decode the body yourself(using jackson for example)

Comment: Besides that, why do you create a filter for handling logins? A regular endpoint would be more fit for this imo.

Comment: @Riiverside, in spring, security is almost always handled by filters.  Including login and logout.

Comment: @hooknc: Actually not. Yes securing endpoints is done through filters(for obvious reasons), but login/logout are still regular endpoints(which can also be custom endpoints created by a user instead of the default provided by spring security). Exception to this might be basic/digest auth, because those really are checked on every request. Filters are used when something should be performed for (nearly) every request(like checking if a user actually has access to the requested resource).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'regular endpoints'.  Do you mean a regular url, like /login?  Then yes, you are correct.

But, the technical behavior of logging in (for Spring) still occurs in a filter.  Please see the following examples [OpenIDAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/openid/OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.html) and [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the json as a request body not as param. Try reading this way,

```
servletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

But servletRequest.getReader() returns a reader that can be read only once.